# Regex match all 1 to 2 digits exclude 4 digits

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match all dates in a paragraph, so any 1 or 2 digit and NOT the a year or 4 digit.
I can capture the 1 or 2 digits but when I try and exclude a 4 digit it captures two 2 digits instead.
Can anyone help me exclude the years?

Heres the expression I was playing with:

```
((?!\d{4})\d{1,2})
```

And heres an example paragraph I would use it on

> 2015 January 16- 25 Array Dubai Shopping Festival Dubai, UAE 2015
>   March 6-9 Array   Port Fairy Folk Festival    Port Fairy, Victoria,
>   Australia 2015 March 12 Array Brunswick Music Festival    Melbourne,
>   Victoria, Australia 2015 March 14-15 Array    Tasmania International Arts
>   Festival  Hobart, Tasmania, Australia 2015 March 21-22
>   Array Castlemaine State Festival  Castlemaine, Victoria, Australia 2016
>   April 26-31 Array Sydney, NSW, Australia  Sydney Royal Easter Show 2016
>   April 1-8 Array   Sydney Royal Easter Show    Sydney, NSW, Australia 2016
>   June 26 Array CEHL Conference NAB Docklands, Melbourne, Victoria,
>   Australia 2016 July 27-30 Array   ‘Fun4Kids’ International Childrens
>   Festival  Warrnambool, Victoria, Australia 2017 January 16-25
>   Array Dubai Shopping Festival Dubai, UAE 2017 March 6-9 Array Port
>   Fairy Folk Festival   Port Fairy, Victoria, Australia 2017 March 12
>   Array Brunswick Music Festival    Melbourne, Victoria, Australia 2017
>   March 14-15 Array Tasmania International Arts Festival    Hobart,
>   Tasmania, Australia 2017 March 21-22 Array    Castlemaine State
>   Festival  Castlemaine, Victoria, Australia

This is generated by users. So the dates could be formatted in any number of ways.

Comment: what's wrong with `\b\d{1,2}\b` ?

Comment: Your regex is also matching 3 digits. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, the easiest way do do it (I think) would be to use *word boundary*.

```
\b\d{1,2}\b
```

It makes sure that to either side of the number, there's **not** a *word* character (which includes digits).

That'll make sure it's not more that 2 digits in a row.

If your intention is to capture the number (as in your experiment) just put the parentheses back around it:

```
(\b\d{1,2}\b)
```

[You can see it work here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wF4mR1/1).